# Unread marks changing to read

Tags: lotus-notes

I have a user who receives email as unread and then randomly, without him clicking on or interacting with the email in any way, the email become marked as read. This was happening with Notes 9.0, so I upgraded him to 9.0.1 and ran the fixpack. Updated his design, made sure the read on preview was unchecked, and made sure the Don't maintain unread marks was also uncheck, He is running Window 7, 64bit, does not have a phone or second computer his email might replicate to. Runs off a local replica. Just not sure how to fix this for him.

Comment: Have you tried to disable the unread marks on the db and re-enable it? does the user have iNotes access? has he changed his password lately? Maybe someone has access to his iNotes account? Maybe someone has a copy of his ID and reads his mail?

Comment: We have tried disabling and re-enabling unread marks. He would have iNotes access, but I'm pretty sure he's never used it. I just rechecked his access control and there isn't anyone listed besides himself and the regular admins (none of whom would open his email). I will have to ask about his password. How else could I track down some one reading his mail?

Comment: "How else could I track down some one reading his mail?" Unread marks are specific to the user, so the unread marks being wrong wouldn't even indicate that someone else is reading his email. You could look at user detail in the database properties if you though someone was reading his email, although calendar viewings also count as reads. Realistically the unread marks are just messed up, it happens.

Answer (score 0):

If he's running off a local, I'd recreate the local once you verified it was in sync with the server and no emails would be lost. I've had some luck just going into all docs and marking everything as read and then it seems to work correctly going forward as new emails are received.

Comment: I recreated the local copy when I tried upgrading to 9.0.1 (blew away the Data directory as well to hopefully clear the problem out). I will have him try the mark all as read option and wait to hear the results.

Comment: User just called to say two new email came in and turned read. I watched him hit refresh to see if it would come back, but they didn't. Any other ideas?

Comment: have you tried replacing the mailfile design?

Comment: We have, replace it with R9 locally. Don't remember if I did Upgrade Folder Design though.

Comment: You might also try moving everything from the inbox into a folder, using designer to delete the $inbox folder and then replacing the design and doing the folder upgrade.

Comment: You can also try toggling unread marks off and on in the db properties and make sure they are set to replicate. Clear replication history between all the replicas and force a replication to sync everything up.